# WPF Simple color binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to bind a background color but for some reason it is not updating the control, I can see it hitting the get of the property but it doesn't update the GUI. Is there something I am missing?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    // ...

    private Color m_myColorProperty;
    public Color MyColorProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return m_myColorProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            m_myColorProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyColorProperty");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding MyColorProperty}"/>
    </Grid.Background>
```

Comment: Where and how are you setting your `MyColorProperty` value?

Comment: what are your imports?  there are 2 different `Color` types, maybe you have the wrong one?

Answer (score 1):

You should bind a Brush type not a color. SolidBrush, Gradient Brush, etc.  if you want a single color use solid brush

Comment: Have you tried this? The SolidColorBrush.Color property is of type  System.Windows.Media.Color: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.color.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using your code as a basis, adding the following inside of the `MainWindow` constructor provided me with a Window sporting a lovely pink background:

```
this.MyColorProperty = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFCC0099");
```

Answer (score 0):

since you're using "this" (a window) as the datacontext, would it be simpler to use a `DependencyProperty` instead of going through the work of implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` ?

Comment: Your RelativeSource binding won't work in that case. Self would be Brush (or Grid not entirely sure) But not the window. ElementName on the window on the other hand works.

Comment: ah yeah. or you'd need `RelativeSource Ancestor` and ancestoroftype window.  But, for the property, I still think that using a DP would be easier than implementing INPC for this kind of thing, since its already a `DependencyObject`

Comment: Yes i would also use a dependency property for that, just wanted to point out that FindAncestor or ElementName is necessary to access the property.